# Disable publish button for admin user

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client

We would like to disable Publish button under the home menu in experience editor for admin users as well in Sitecore SXA.

Tried approach :
I went to core database `/sitecore/content/Application/webedit/ribbons/webedit/Experience Editor /publish/publish` path and tried to remove click textbox  text `(item:publish(id=$Target)` After that I am still able to see the functionality.

I have a requirement to remove the functionality of the click event, not the button. When I am clicking on publish button then it shows the publish item popup. I don't want to open this functionality.

Comment: In my opinion this seems unnecessary. Admins should not be poking around editing content. Perhaps this is an issue with granting too much access to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not a good solution but If you don't want this functionality anymore or completely remove this then one thing you can do is delete or rename or update the code in the JS file that is handling this click event from your Sitecore application root.

Here is the location of this file.

```
wwwroot\<your-appplication-root>\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\Commands\Publish.js
```

And it will stop the publish functionality.

I will suggest you to modify the JS written in this file on the click event and just use return in the functions.

After modifying your changes, run the application in incognito mode to verify the latest changes. Then it will reflect.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible out of the box but there are a couple of ways you can try out.

1. Custom `Command` to restrict the Publish button. Refer this for more details ([Link](https://sitecorefootsteps.blogspot.com/2016/11/custom-sitecore-command-to-disable-or.html))
2. Use `Rules Engine` to control show/hide. Refer this for more details ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37659935/restrict-sitecore-publishing/37691414#37691414))
3. **Not recommended** - Delete item `/sitecore/content/Application/webedit/ribbons/webedit/Experience Editor /publish/publish`

Hope it helps!